# Is there an adjustable voltage converter that could take an input of 18 volts to a 0-18v and handle an amp draw of 20 to 30 amps?

Tags: voltage, converter

Trying to change a power tool from a 9.6 v 3.3 ah nimh battery to an 18v 5 ah lithium Milwaukee battery

Comment: not generally adjustable, when you get to that power level it needs to be fairly specific, as any dip in efficiency tends to cook things,

Comment: Such a high power converter will cost at least double what an appropriate battery will cost. I wouldn't be surprised if it cost 3x or 4x.

Comment: what stability of Vout, versus load?

Comment: I use Milwaukee tools, myself. Those batteries are not cheap. Perhaps Milwaukee should read this and come up with adapters to competing tool manufacturers and ***eat*** their competitors' lunches.

Comment: I should correct it before it gets buried, you can build such a voltage converter, e.g. https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator can give you the parts and components, just left to yourself to lay it out and order the parts, that would be the cheapest approach at the cost of your own time.

Comment: there is but shopping questions re off-topic